# Test "Send Email" action in Flow

Tags: email, visual-workflow

Is there a possibility to test if email was sent from Flow in UnitTest? I know that there is Limits.getEmailInvocations() method which works fine if email was sent from apex. However, seems that this method doesn't work if email was sent from Flow action.

Answer (score 0):

You can check email logs and verify if the email is sent or not.

Kindly refer this below article to setup the email log:-

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_monitor_emails_sent_from_salesforce.htm&type=5

Answer (score 0):

You can test this indirectly if the Flow also adds a Task or ChatterPost *after* the Send Email action.

Then, your testmethod can check the presence of the Task/FeedPost using SOQL